# Transfer my article content from Liferay portal 6.1.1 to Liferay portal 6.2

Tags: migration, liferay, liferay-6, data-migration

I have a liferay portal 6.1.1 with a lot of article contents on it. Now I want to migrate these articles to my new liferay portal 6.2.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The standard upgrade process takes care of this.

- Have a Backup
- Restore your backup in a new system (this neatly makes sure that your backup procedure actually works at the same time)
- Install Liferay 6.2 on top of the 6.1 installation. Follow the other upgrade instructions from the documentation
- Update all of your plugins to 6.2 as well
- All of your content is now in 6.2